# Which Esperanto youtubers have subtitles to their videos?

Tags: culture, learning

I think that learning through watching is great. Youtube is really popular among young people. Beginners might not be patient enough to watch if they only understand a fraction of what is said. Subtitles would solve this problem, and I believe they'd still learn a whole lot. Which YouTube-channels can I recommend to my students?

Answer (score 7):

These videos are consistently subtitled in English: https://www.youtube.com/user/Evildela/videos

These videos have subtitles in Esperanto: https://www.youtube.com/user/bookboxinc/search?query=esperanto

Answer (score 5):

YouTube is a constantly changing environment. Looking at informal surveys about Esperanto YouTubers from a year ago versus today, the only consistent name is the "Evildela" channel referenced in Tony's answer. There are a lot of people working to add subtitles to their videos, and there are people who are currently doing so who may stop suddenly if their life situation or mood changes.

**One thing to consider is to take advantage of YouTube's filters to search only for videos with captions.**

On my own channel (Esperanto Variety Show), I generally release a video, then add captions in the original language (English or Esperanto), then add a translation in the other language (Esperanto or English). I will sometimes add a third language. This is all done as time allows, and sometimes I can get the subtitles up more quickly than others.